# Handling multiple possible @RequestParam values when making request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, findall, http-request-parameters

I have an endpoint to get all Posts, I also have multiple @RequestParams used to filter and search for values etc.

The issue I'm having is that when trying to filter based on specific @RequestParams, I would need to have multiple checks to see whether that specific parameter is passed when calling the endpoint, so in my Controller I have something like this. The parameters are optional, I also have parameters for Pagination etc, but I left it out below.

I have these criteria:

```java
@RequestParam(required=false) List<String> brand - Used to filter by multiple brands
@RequestParam(required=false) String province - Used to filter by province
@RequestParam(required=false) String city - Used to filter by city
// Using these 2 for getting Posts within a certain price range
@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0", required = false) String minValue - Used to filter by min price
@RequestParam(defaultValue = "5000000", required = false) String maxValue - Used to filter by max price
```

---

I also have this in my **Controller** when checking which of my service methods to call based on the parameters passed.

```java
        if(query != null) {
            pageTuts = postService.findAllPosts(query, pagingSort);
        } else if(brand != null) {
            pageTuts = postService.findAllByBrandIn(brand, pagingSort);
        } else if(minValue != null && maxValue != null) {
            pageTuts = postService.findAllPostsByPriceBetween(minValue, maxValue, pagingSort);
        } else if(brand != null & minValue != null & maxValue != null) {
            pageTuts = postService.findAllPostsByPriceBetween(minValue, maxValue, pagingSort);
        } else {
            // if no parameters are passed in req, just get all the Posts available
            pageTuts = postService.findAllPosts(pagingSort);
        }
    // I would need more checks to handle all parameters
```

---

The issue is that I'm struggling to find out, if I need this condition for each and every possible parameter, which will be a lot of checks and Repository/Service methods based on that parameter.

For example in my **Repository** I have abstract methods like these:

```java
    Page<Post> findAllByProvince(String province, Pageable pageable);
    Page<Post> findAllByCity(String city, Pageable pageable);
    Page<Post> findAllByProvinceAndCity(String province, String city, Pageable pageable);
    Page<Post> findAllByBrandInAndProvince(List<String> brand, String province, Pageable pageable);
```

And I'd need much more so I could handle the other potential values, ie. findAllByPriceBetween(), findAllByCityAndPriceBetween(), findAllByProvinceAndPriceBetween()...

So I'd like some suggestions on how to handle this?.

---

**Edit**

Managed to get it working by overriding the toPredicate method as shown by @M. Deinum with some small tweaks according to my use case.

```java
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root root, CriteriaQuery query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        // min/max is never not set as they have default values
        predicates.add(builder.between(root.get("price"), params.getMinValue(), params.getMaxValue()));

        if (params.getProvince() != null) {
            predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("province"), params.getProvince()));
        }

        if (params.getCity() != null) {
            predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("city"), params.getCity()));
        }


        
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(params.getBrand())) {
        Expression<String> userExpression = root.get("brand");
        Predicate p = userExpression.in(params.getBrand());
            predicates.add(p);
        }
        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
```

Comment: Bind to an object which holds all the values. Then use predicates to dynamically build a query based on which are set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create an object to hold your variables instead of individual elements.
2. Move the logic to your service and pass the object and pageable to the service
3. Ditch those `findAll` methods from your repository and add the `JpaSpecificationExecutor` in your extends clause.
4. In the service create `Predicate` and use the `JpaSpecificationExecutor.findAll` to return what you want.

```java
public class PostSearchParameters {
 
  private String province;
  private String city;
  private List<String> brand;
  private int minValue = 0;
  private int maxValue = 500000;

  //getters/setters or when on java17+ use a record instead of class
}
```

Predicate

```java
public class PostSearchParametersSpecification implements Specification {

  private final PostSearchParameters params;

  PostSearchParametersPredicate(PostSearchParameters params) {
    this.params=params;
  }

  @Override
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    // min/max is never not set as they have default values
    predicates.add(builder.between(root.get("price", params.getMinValue(), params.getMaxValue());

    if (params.getProvince() != null) {
      predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("province"), params.getProvince());
    }

    if (params.getCity() != null) {
      predicates.add(builder.equal(root.get("city"), params.getCity());
    }

    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(params.getBrand()) {
      predicates.add(builder.in(root.get("brand")).values( params.getBrand());
    }

    return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
  }
}
```

Repository

```java
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Post> {}
```

Service method

```java
public Page<Post> searchPosts(PostSearchParameters params, Pageable pageSort) {
  PostSearchParametersSpecification specification =
    new PostSearchParametersSpecification(params)
  return repository.findAll(specification, pageSort);
}
```

Now you can query on all available parameters, adding one is extending/modifying the predicate and you are good to go.

See also the Spring Data JPA Reference guide on [Specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to understand it and will let you know how I get along, also, should the PostSearchParametersPredicate  class not implement Specification instead of Predicate? Since the toPredicate() method is a method within the Specification Interface.

Comment: My bad, that is what you get from typing it from the top of your head. Changed the implements.

Comment: Thank you, managed to get it working with some few tweaks since I was having issues with the  predicates.add(builder.in(root.get("brand", params.getBrand());, I used Expression<String> s = root.get("brand") and also created a separate Predicate for the IN clause, then I just added that Predicate to my List of predicates. Thanks once again, it is much cleaner and clutter free this way.

Comment: Edited my post with what I have now, please let me know if that's fine

Comment: If it works for you then why should I need to review your code :).